# Destroy ssh tunnel if exists and create new one

Tags: ssh, cron, remote-access

I open a reverse ssh tunnel after the OS reboot (on office pc to a dedicated server). I put it into cron by `@reboot /myssh.sh`. The ssh opens a port on server.
**My problem is :** 
If the OS (office pc) suddenly dies and bootup again the cron will run the script again while the port on server still in use by previous session, and of course the ssh will fail (because it tries to open an open port on server). That's why I can't access the office pc from server if the office pc rebooted.

**The questions:**

1. How to check ssh or port on server (and end the previous session) before reopen a reverse ssh again from office pc?
2. Do I have to do it by accessor-side(server) or host-side(office pc)?

**The Goal**

I want the ssh tunnel keeps alive, no matter what happens. If internet connection lost, I still can access the office pc once the internet available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a control socket

I just discovered what seems to be the most correct method from [AutoSSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241063/bash-script-to-setup-a-temporary-ssh-tunnel).

However **Multiplexing** is a very big subject and can be used for other things. [Source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing)

The idea in [Bash script to setup...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241063/bash-script-to-setup-a-temporary-ssh-tunnel) is to use and integrated method called **Control Socket**. Through this method you can command an old connection to die. However you will have to test if this will work even after a reboot.

### What you are asking for:

### Kill process on remote server

The tunnel is a process running on the remote machine. You can generate a script verifying that no previous instance of the tunnel is runnig.

Suppose that `ssh -f -R XXXXX:localhost:YYYYY user@server -N` is your original command. `XXXXX` stands for the port used on the remote server and YYYYY the port on your local machine.

Then you can check that no process is listening on port `XXXXX` on your remote server using **lsof**. However you will need to be able to use **`sudo`** in order to get the Process ID (**pid**) of the program listening on the port.

As soon as you find the **pid** using the port, you can just run at the server the command `kill thePID`.

### Bash Script For getting the PID

The script bellow should should display the **pid** that is listening on `XXXXX` and save it on `/tmp/remTunPID`. If your user does not have **sudo** access it will not work, the PID will not be visible for security reasons.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rPort=XXXXX
theUser=[replace with remote user name]
server=[replace with your server]
if [ -a /tmp/sshPID1 ]
   then
      rm /tmp/sshPID1
fi
if [ -a /tmp/sshPID2 ]
   then
      rm /tmp/sshPID2
fi
if [ -a /tmp/remTunPID ]
   then
      rm /tmp/remTunPID
fi
echo "Enter [sudo] password for ${theUser}:"
ssh -t $theUser@$server "sudo lsof -i tcp:${rPort} | grep  IPv4" > /tmp/sshPID1
while read -a A; do echo ${A[6]}; done < /tmp/sshPID1 > /tmp/sshPID2
cat /tmp/sshPID2 | grep -v pass | tee /tmp/remTunPID
if [ -s /tmp/remTunPID ]
   then
      thePID=$(cat /tmp/remTunPID)
      echo The process $thePID is running at $server listening to $rPort
   else
      echo No process is listening on $rPort at $server
fi
```

Change the values of `rPort`, `theUser` and `server` to the values of your remote port, remote user and server(domain or IP) respectively.

This command will prompt you for your **sudo** password in order to continue, but don't worry if you understand a bit of **bash** you can see that it is being requested directly by **ssh** with the `-t` option.

### Actually Kill the Process

You could add a command to this script inside the `if then else fi` statement to kill the process:

```
if [ -s /tmp/remTunPID ]
   then
      thePID=$(cat /tmp/remTunPID)
      echo The process $thePID is running on $server and listening on $rPort
      echo Will attempt to kill $thePID
      ssh $theUser@$server "kill ${thePID}"
   else
      echo No process is listening on $rPort
fi
```

This should kill the process only if the port is being used. But it will kill the process even if your machine did not start the tunnel to begin with.

### AutoSSH

[AutoSSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241063/bash-script-to-setup-a-temporary-ssh-tunnel) seems to be a good tool to handle what you want to achieve. Maybe you should take a look.
[SOURCE](https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But, unfortunately I'm not a `sudoer` of the server. So, I can't run `lsof` things. If I am able to run sudo then your answer is the right solution for the question.

Comment: Multiplexing --sounds interesting. I will learn more about it and I will try out `autossh`, I hope it can fulfil my needs.

Comment: do you know how to use `autossh` with `sshpass`? Because I always failed using public key

Comment: I have never implemented **autossh**. Sorry. I added a source for an example of a previous answer. Take a look.